# How to select the count of entities, where a time series date is between start and end date of that entity

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to select a day series, kind of like this:

```
SELECT generate_series(
   timestamp without time zone '2016-10-16',
   timestamp without time zone '2016-10-17',
   '1 day')
```

Further I got entities which always have a startdate and an enddate.
With the above query, I would like to select the amount (count) of entities, which have that day in the series being inside both dates.

Output would be (kinda) like this:
[select output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CaGp.png)

Any help is appreciated!

edit: Here is a sample table:

```
table occurrences (
    datestart DATE
    dateend DATE
)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please share entity table structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table entities (id int, startdate date,enddate date);
 insert into entities values(1, '2016-10-10','2016-10-18');
 insert into entities values(1, '2016-10-10','2016-10-16');
 insert into entities values(1, '2016-10-15','2016-10-16');
 insert into entities values(1, '2016-10-17','2016-10-18');
```

Query:

```
 with dateseries as
 (
 SELECT generate_series(
    timestamp without time zone '2016-10-16',
    timestamp without time zone '2016-10-20',
    '1 day')
 
 )
 select generate_series,
 (select count(*) from entities e where d.generate_series between e.startdate and e.enddate)  entities_count
 from dateseries d
```

Output:

| generate_series | entities_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-10-16 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2016-10-17 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2016-10-18 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2016-10-19 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 2016-10-20 00:00:00 | 0 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=53411dee807a0ab29ab8388051de7da7)*

Comment: @Don you are most welcome. It's nice to know that it helped. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT gs.dte, COUNT(e.entity_id)
FROM generate_series('2016-10-16'::date, '2016-10-17'::date, '1 day') gs(dte) LEFT JOIN
     entities e
     ON e.startdate < gs.dte + interval '1 day' AND
        e.enddate >= gs.dte
GROUP BY gs.dte;
```

Dates seem sufficient for the logic you want to implement, but you can, of course, use timestamps instead.